# Create a single dimension from multiple fields

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

So essentially I want to create a single dimension by using their respective column/filename, say a Listbox called Asset, to make a selection on this laptop, desktops, server, and tablet.

Many thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI5ce.png)

Comment: If you just make a list box with the dimension you want then it is automatically "wired" behind the scenes and you can make selections in it and that will trigger a recalculation of the table based on the new selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd want is the `CrossTable` prefix (see the Qlik Help [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/use-crosstable-prefix.htm?)). It allows you to "pivot" a table so that 1 record with multiple columns becomes multiple records with just 2 columns (1 column for field name, 1 column for field value).

So given your table, which we'll call **[Data]**:

| Code | # of laptop | # of desktop | # of servers | # of tablet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| a2 | 23 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| a3 | 12 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| f1 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 0 |
| e3 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 |
| z2 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 0 |

...you can use the following Qlik script in the Data Load Editor to get the desired output:

```
[Pivoted]:
CrossTable ([Device], [DeviceCount], 1) Load * Resident [Data];

Drop Table [Data];


[New Data]:
NoConcatenate Load
    [Code]
  , Capitalize(SubField([Device], ' ', -1)) as [Device]
  , [DeviceCount]
Resident [Pivoted];

Drop Table [Pivoted];
```

That should give you this result:

| Code | Device | DeviceCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a2 | Desktop | 3 |
| a2 | Laptop | 23 |
| a2 | Servers | 0 |
| a2 | Tablet | 0 |
| a3 | Desktop | 5 |
| a3 | Laptop | 12 |
| a3 | Servers | 0 |
| a3 | Tablet | 0 |
| d1 | Desktop | 1 |
| d1 | Laptop | 0 |
| d1 | Servers | 0 |
| d1 | Tablet | 1 |
| e3 | Desktop | 12 |
| e3 | Laptop | 0 |
| e3 | Servers | 0 |
| e3 | Tablet | 0 |
| f1 | Desktop | 14 |
| f1 | Laptop | 0 |
| f1 | Servers | 0 |
| f1 | Tablet | 0 |
| z2 | Desktop | 5 |
| z2 | Laptop | 0 |
| z2 | Servers | 1 |
| z2 | Tablet | 0 |